# Significance of --connection-manager in Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, teradata, sqoop

I have written sqoop script to import data from Teradata to Hive.

```
`sqoop import \
--connect $JDBC_URL \
--driver com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver \
--username $Username \
--password $Password \
--table $TD_Table \
--hive-import \
--hive-overwrite \  
--hive-drop-import-delims \
--hive-table $Hive_Database.$Hive_Staging_Table \
--split-by $Split_Col \
-m $Mapper_Number`
```

Above script gives warning as

`--connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to     org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.`

But when i used **--connection-manager** with above script my **--hive-drop-import-delims** and **--hive-overwrite** stoped working

I'm trying to undersdtand what is the significance of connection-manager parameter how will it effect my imports if I'm ommiting it

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `--driver` above. Also, make sure you have the connection manager set in `/etc/sqoop/conf/managers.d`. Here are the steps to get it working:

1. `cd /etc/sqoop/conf`
2. `mkdir managers.d && cd managers.d`
3. `echo '<manager factory class> = <manager factory jar>' > td_connector.txt`

Manager factory jar should be put in `/var/lib/sqoop` and one can be downloaded from [Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/downloads/connectors/sqoop/teradata/1-2c5-powered-by-teradata.html).

Comment: thanks for the reply but I'm using Hortonworks.can you provide link for the same?