# How can I find the connection managers supported by sqoop?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I need some help...

I'm developing a sqoop guide for teach new employees how to use sqoop. There is a flag called --connection-manager, and I must know, what jar file should I list, to return all the connection-manager classes supported by my configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code, specifically https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/manager/SupportedManagers.java#L26, you'll see:

```
public enum SupportedManagers {
    MYSQL(JdbcDrivers.MYSQL.getSchemePrefix(), true), POSTGRES(JdbcDrivers.POSTGRES.getSchemePrefix(), true),
    HSQLDB(JdbcDrivers.HSQLDB.getSchemePrefix(), false), ORACLE(JdbcDrivers.ORACLE.getSchemePrefix(), true),
    SQLSERVER(JdbcDrivers.SQLSERVER.getSchemePrefix(), false),  CUBRID(JdbcDrivers.CUBRID.getSchemePrefix(), false),  
    JTDS_SQLSERVER(JdbcDrivers.JTDS_SQLSERVER.getSchemePrefix(), false), DB2(JdbcDrivers.DB2.getSchemePrefix(), false),
    NETEZZA(JdbcDrivers.NETEZZA.getSchemePrefix(), true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to know, what connection manager classes are available in my environment specifically, because I don't know if the instalation is exactly equal to github. So I need to know where Sqoop finds the correct jar file

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388465/significance-of-connection-manager-in-sqoop.  Depending on whether you're using a HDP or CDH distro the exact path might change and you need to contact your Hadoop admin to find that out.